# how to fetch substring using perl with certain pattern?

Tags: perl, substring

I am trying to get a substring out of certain string. like below:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -I. -I./ --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -arch armv7 --sysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -g -MMD -MF libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.d -MT - -c -o - libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.S -E
```

I want to get string `ac3dsp_armv6.S` out, how to do it using Perl?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, the only thing changes in the string is *.s like ac3dsp_armv6.S or ac3dsp_armv7.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  my $string = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -I. -I./ --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -arch armv7 --sysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -g -MMD -MF libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.d -MT - -c -o - libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.S -E';
  my @r = split(/ / ,( split /\//, $string )[-1]);
  print $r[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach.

```
my $string = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -I. -I./ --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -arch armv7 --sysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -g -MMD -MF libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.d -MT - -c -o - libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.S -E'

my ($result)=$string=~m#/(.+?)\s+\-E\s*\z#gis;
print $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to answer this question as there is not enough information to go by. There are plenty of ways to extract the string that are not guaranteed to be generic.

Is the string coming as fixed-width format? Probably not.

What is so unique about the sought-after substring that one could use to extract it?

Have you considered using regular expressions?

[`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) should provide the required know-how to achieve the stated objective.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, the only thing changes in the string is *.s like ac3dsp_armv6.S or ac3dsp_armv7.S